# Sign of a Function over $[0,\pi]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functions

> Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R} $ such that $\left| \lambda  \right| \ne 1$
>
> $$f_\lambda  (x)=(λ\cos x−1)(λ−\cos x)$$
>
> - Show that :
> - **For  $|λ|<1$**,
>
> $$f_λ(x)=\begin{cases} <0 & x> \arccos λ \\ >0 &x< \arccos λ \end{cases}  \textrm{ over } [0,\pi]$$
>
> - **For  $|λ|>1$**,
>   $$f_λ(x)=\begin{cases} <0 & x> \arccos 1/λ \\ >0 &x< \arccos 1/λ \end{cases}  \text{ over } [0,\pi]$$

my attempts

We've

$$f_λ(x)=λ\cos x−1)(λ−\cos x)$$

- **for  $|λ|<1$**,
  The factor $(λ\cos x−1)$ has no solution over $[0,\pi]$ then So he keeps a constant sign :

since  $|λ|<1$ then  $|λ\cos(x)| < 1$ thus $(λ\cos x−1)<0$ over $[0,\pi]$

and for $(λ−\cos x)=\begin{cases}>0 & x> \arccos λ \\<0 &x< \arccos λ \end{cases}$   over $[0,\pi]$

> Thus $$f_λ(x)=\begin{cases}>0 & x> \arccos λ \\<0 &x< \arccos λ \end{cases}   over [0,\pi]$$

- **for  $|λ|>1$**,
  The factor $(λ−\cos x)$ has no solution over $[0,\pi]$ then So he keeps a constant sign:

Since $|λ|>1$ i.e. ($λ > 1$ and $λ <- 1$) then

- if $λ > 1$ then $(λ−\cos x) > 0$
- if  $λ < -1$ then $(λ−\cos x) < 0$

i can't manage with this

and for $(λ\cos x−1)=\begin{cases}<0 & x> \arccos 1/λ \\>0 &x< \arccos 1/λ \end{cases}$   over $[0,\pi]$

> Thus  $$f_λ(x)=\begin{cases} ?? & x> \arccos 1/λ \\ ?? &x< \arccos 1/λ \end{cases}   over [0,\pi]$$

1. **Is my reasoning correct here ?**
2. **Is There other ways to prove it** ?

Comment: You have no reason to go to the derivative of the function,  you're just examining the sign of the function.  The reasoning approach you are taking is sound though to look at the regions where each () is being multiplied is positive/negative

Comment: @Alan it's typo